# Web API ExceptionLogger

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using IExceptionLogger and ExceptionHandler for logging and error handling globally for my web api service.

Now Is there any way to read the POST data from ExceptionLoggerContext context. ? Just because i would like to save the POST data along with exception details.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I've found is to parse the `ExceptionLoggerContext.ExceptionContext` in your `ExceptionLogger`/`IExceptionLogger` implementation.

`ExceptionLoggerContext.ExceptionContext` is of type `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionContext`.

There are a few nested objects you have to navigate, but at some point, you will find:

```
((System.Web.Http.ApiController)exceptionContext.ControllerContext.Controller).ActionContext.ActionArguments
```

which contains a `ValueCollection` with all the arguments of your `FORM`.

In my solution I've implemented something like this:

```
public class MyExceptionContext
    {
    public Dictionary<string, object>.ValueCollection ActionArguments { get; set; }

    public MyExceptionContext(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
    {
        try
        {
        this.ActionArguments = ((System.Web.Http.ApiController)exceptionContext.ControllerContext.Controller).ActionContext.ActionArguments.Values;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I pass my constructor `ExceptionLoggerContext.ExceptionContext`; it will populate the dictionary `ActionArguments` with all the values posted.

You can find a [demo project](https://github.com/Leftyx/OwinWebApiSelfHost) on Github. It's a self-hosted (owin) web.api application.
In my [Startup](https://github.com/Leftyx/OwinWebApiSelfHost/blob/master/OwinWebApiSelfHost/Startup.cs#L28) I've defined my custom implementation of `IExceptionLogger` and `IExceptionHandler`.

*In this sample app I've used Serilog to stream exception on disk.*

If you try to post a form to the test controller, I'll [throw an exception](https://github.com/Leftyx/OwinWebApiSelfHost/blob/master/OwinWebApiSelfHost/api/TestController.cs#L76) which will be trapped by a global handler and persisted on the file system with some info.

If you download and run the example found in Github you can use Fiddler to test it:

```
POST http://localhost:9667/api/exception HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:9667
Content-Length: 40

username=stackoverflow&password=password
```