# ASP.Net Web API: Global Exception Logging

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2

I have logging implemented in one of my ASP.Net Web API project. It works alright and sends the details correctly. However in case of POST request, the logged details are insufficient. For example, it sends the requested url but the request parameters are unavailable. We need the post request body in order to investigate the issue correctly. The code I am using is below.

```
public class GlobalExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            SendErrorMail(context);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}

private void SendErrorMail(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        var Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request;
        if (Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
        {
           //Here I need to get all the variables available with the post request.
        }
        //send email with the exception details
    }
}
```

I am unable to read the posted data/body with the request. Can someone provide a sample implementation of reading post data/body?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best practice to log request body on failed requests in Application Insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769413/what-is-the-best-practice-to-log-request-body-on-failed-requests-in-application)

Comment: Look over at the following links:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265211/web-api-exceptionlogger?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589968/as-net-web-api-global-exception-handler-cannot-access-request-content